# How to get spring effect (tween) similar to shown in the link

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

I saw [this mouseover tween](http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_129_circle), and I just love it. Just mouse over the thumbs to see the spring effect. I know it may be easy for professionals but I have no idea how this has been done.

I would be very greatful to anyone who can suggest how I can get the similar effect, or better still, suggest a tutorial where I can learn this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). Use Bounce.easeOut with a duration of about 0.75.
Make sure you import TweenLite

```
package
{
    import com.greensock.TweenLite;
    import com.greensock.easing.Bounce;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Testerooni extends Sprite
    {
        public var ball:Sprite = new Sprite();
        public function Testerooni()
        {
            createBall();
            addChild(ball);
            ball.x = 100;
            ball.y = 100;
            ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,bounceOver);
            ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,bounceOut);
        }

        protected function bounceOver(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            TweenLite.to(ball,0.5,{scaleX:2,scaleY:2,ease:Bounce.easeOut});
        }

        protected function bounceOut(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            TweenLite.to(ball,0.5,{scaleX:1,scaleY:1,ease:Bounce.easeOut});
        }

        private function createBall():void
        {
            ball.graphics.lineStyle(1);
            ball.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF,0.4);
            ball.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,15);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for taking time to reply. Thanks Jacob.

Comment: Is it not possible without use of TweenLite. Actually, I have never used TweenLite so far.

Comment: " I have never used TweenLite so far" well now is the perfect time to learn :) You will love it!

Comment: @sanjaytripathi if this answers your question, you should accept it as the answer.